# How to install the mxnet-1.4.1(CPU-Version) offline in Windows 10 stackoverflow?

Tags: python, conda, mxnet

I want to try 'GluonTS - Probabilistic Time Series Modeling in Python'.And GluonTS is a Python toolkit for probabilistic time series modeling, built around Apache MXNet (incubating). I must install MXNet 1.4.1, then install GluonTS to try use it.
But my computer cannot link to internet,The installed OS of My PC  is windows 10,so I download 'mxnet-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl' to install,An error occurred as follows：

(mxnet) H:\PythonApp\Mxnet\2020-3-27>conda install --offline mxnet-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- mxnet-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

I am a beginner, don't know what to do,Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are trying install is a pip-file, to install it just activate your conda environment and then:
`pip install mxnet-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl`
If you don't have pip, you will have to install that using anaconda first.